# How to construct a big regular formula for a model in R?

Tags: r, variables, regression, modeling, prediction

I am trying create model to predict "y" from data "D" that contain predictor x1 to x100 and other 200 variables . since all Xs are not stored consequently I can't call them by column.

I can't use `ctree( y ~ , data = D)`  because other variables , Is there a way that I can refer them x1:100 ?? in the model ?

instead of writing a very long code

```
ctree( y = x1 + x2 + x..... x100)
```

Some recommendation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct your formula as a text string, and convert it with `as.formula`.

```
vars <- names(D)[1:100] # or wherever your desired predictors are
fm <- paste("y ~", paste(vars, collapse="+"))
fm <- as.formula(fm)

ctree(fm, data=D, ...)
```

Answer (score 8):

Two more. The simplest in my mind is to subset the data:

```
ctree(y ~ ., data = D[, c("y", paste0("x", 1:100))]
```

Or a more functional approach to building dynamic formulas:

```
ctree(reformulate(paste0("x", 1:100), "y"), data = D)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
fml = as.formula(paste("y", paste0("x", 1:100, collapse=" + "), sep=" ~ "))
ctree(fmla)
```